# shared memory not support string or char* of class instance?

Tags: ubuntu, g++

my problem is read string of char* of instance

i have tried string and string change to char*

this is write process

```cpp
int* state = pVec[0].getState();
uint8_t* buffer = pVec[0].getBuffer();
sem_t* semaphore = pVec[0].getSem();
DBData* setup = pVec[0].getSetup();
DBData test_DBData = DBData(1, 2, 3, "time", "url", 4, "vms", 5, "roi", "dch", "settings");

if(state[1] == WRITE_TERN)
{
    memcpy(setup, &test_DBData, sizeof(DBData));
    state[1] = READ_TERN;
}
cout << setup->getROI() << endl;
```

and this is read process

```cpp
int* state = pVec[0].getState();
uint8_t* buffer = pVec[0].getBuffer();
sem_t* semaphore = pVec[0].getSem();
DBData* setup = pVec[0].getSetup();

DBData tmp = DBData();
if(state[1] == READ_TERN)
{
    cout << setup->getROI() << endl;
}
```

write process can read setup->getROI() but when i try to read setup->getROI() on the read process has occurred Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: It's not clear what `DBData` is. Its sources do not seem to be publicly available.